# video player that limits time to view before call to action or preventing additional view time

Tags: html, video, paypal

So I have a conundrum that I have no idea how to solve, but pretty sure there is a solution out there - hoping someone's expertise can guide me in the right direction.

I have an AVS implementation (basically a tube site CMS) and I want to limit the time users/visitors can view each video. Essentially, I'd like non-registered users to be able to view the first 30 seconds (may increase this to a minute) before being "forced" to register a free account, and then once becoming a registered user, they would get 1 minute per video (may also raise this at a later time) which would then force them to pay for a monthly subscription if they desired the ability to view any videos in entirety.

And to combat abuse of the call-to-action rules for viewing, I'd want to ensure that it's hard or near impossible to "cheat" the logic (perhaps with IP/Authentication/cookie checks).

I'd want the video player to be local and not some external video player where I would have to pay additional monthly for the service (I already pay for coding, hosting, bandwidth etc). Ideally I would also be able to manipulate the timing between calls to action from the CMS or manually in the code. While not directly tied in, I would also want the subscription feature tied in to paypal so I can accept payments.

Anyone know of an open source, html5 or commercial video player where I can do just what I ask without incurring monthly fees? I am ok with paying a reasonable one time cost for the player, but don't want to have a player I am stuck with paying monthly.

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Since nobody has answered, I will suggest a workaround.  Rather than program the video to stop and ask for payment, why not simply show a 'demo' clip of the video that ends by displaying a "Purchase Now" button added to the standard HTML5 video player? Then once the video is paid for, a page would be generated that confirms payment and includes the video page where the full video can be viewed.  Also, an email (with link) would be generated and sent to the purchaser's email (acquired during payment/registration), in case they need to replay the video again. There are also video players available without monthly fees, that only charge a commission when a video is actually sold. I imagine you are trying to find the cheapest option since you mentioned that you don't want to pay any more monthly fees and if your sales volume is low, then maybe the straight commission option is best for you. Amazon S3, Cleeng, Digital Pass and TinyPass all have low cost options.

Comment: Thanks Vonada, that seems to be a pretty good option - just curious of how I would go about doing it. Sorry about the delay in seeing this!